# How would I achieve a set of instructions on an array for each item?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm not sure how else to word this, but I have an array of songs, and I need to play them, but after the array finishes, it needs to loop.
I need it to look something like this:

```
let playlist = [
    {
        name: "value"
    },
    {
        name: "value"
    }
]

function myFunc() {
    console.log(playlist[0]); // Log the first song
    console.log(playlist[1]); // After the first song finishes playing log this song
    // Once finished with this, repeat again.
}
```

It's basically playing a playlist, and setting it to repeat.
Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to play the songs?

Comment: Just another function. Using it in conjunction with Discord.js as a 24/7 music bot.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this and let me know:

```
let playlist = [
    {
        name: "value",
        src: "song.wave",
    },
    {
        name: "value",
        src: "sg.wave",
    }
];

function getDuration(src){
    var music = new Audio(src);
    music.addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {
  let duration = music.duration;
  return duration;
  });
}

function playThePlaylist(playlist) {
    let srcSongs = playlist.map(song => song.src);
    let counterSongsPlayed = 0;
      var durationSong = getDuration(song);
      song.addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {
       setInterval(function(){
        if(durationSong == song.currentTime || counterSongsPlayed == 0){
            var song = new Audio(srcSongs[counterSongsPlayed]);
                song.play();
            counterSongsPlayed++;
         }

         if(counterSongsPlayed > srcSongs.length)
           counterSongsPlayed = 0;
       }, 1000);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you basically want to call your playlist function again and again as i understand it . so you can use setinterval() function with a time interval after which you want to call that function again like so:
(you have to use something like a button to call that function)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>
<p>After clicking away the alert box, an new alert box will appear in 3 seconds. This goes on forever...</p>
<button onclick="myFunc()">Try it</button>

<script>
let playlist = [
    {
        name: "value"
    },
    {
        name: "value"
    }
]

function myFunc() {
   setInterval(function(){ console.log(playlist[0]); console.log(playlist[1]);}, 3000);  // Log the first song
  // After the first song finishes playing log this song
    // Once finished with this, repeat again.
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.